# Connect Text Box to Table

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'm new in ASP.net and started my first Website Project. I want to connect the text box to my table which is "Details" please see the code below:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p class="style2">
        <br />
        DETAILS FORMS</p>
    <p>
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 117px;">
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="ID :"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="style3">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Date Recieved  :"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DRInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Date Commision :"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DCINput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style5">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Sender"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem>Angeles</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Aurora</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bataan</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bulacan</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database1ConnectionString1 %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [Sender] FROM [Details]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style10">
                    </td>
                <td class="style11">

                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

                </td>
                <td class="style11">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style6">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td class="style7">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td class="style7">
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

And this is the Code behind it:

```
public partial class Data : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void DRInput_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

What would be my code to bind the textbox to save details in my table "Details" and when I click the button it will be save on table "Details" . Hoping anyone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question. What are you trying to accomplish

Comment: hi sir, just wanted to know on the code behind to be able to link my Text box in "details" table.if i save the information on text box. it will also save the information on my "details" table.hoping you could help.thanks

Answer (score 0):

In you particular case it doesn't look like you're displaying a *list* of data but instead the details of an item.

The simple approach would be to assign the text property of the textbox as part of the page request eg within page load event of the page.

```
DRInput.Text = detailsModel.DRInput;
```

and then when the page is submitted assign the textbox's text value back to your object.

```
detailsModel.DRInput = DRInput.Text;
```

Since you're new to ASP.Net; perhaps best to start with tutorial sites for example w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_demo_intro.asp or asp.net/web-forms then come back and ask your questions

Comment: hi sir,where will i insert it? sorry but im new in asp.thanks!

Comment: Perhaps best to start with tutorial sites for example http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_demo_intro.asp or http://www.asp.net/web-forms then come back and ask your questions.